# Vue.js : variables can be displayed in <template>, but cannot be used in mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue.js, I tried to load a file `config.json` from `/public` folder so that some settings can be changed during runtime.

I can now load the file, but then in my `.vue` file, I can display the setting variable on the `<template>` part, but cannot get the variable on the `<script>` part. The following is my `.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <pre>ApiBaseUrl: {{ ApiBaseUrl }}</pre>
    {{ baseUrl }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      baseUrl: null,
    };
  },
  mounted: () => {
    this.baseUrl = this.ApiBaseUrl;
  },
};
</script>
```

so I can correctly show the line `ApiBaseUrl: {{ ApiBaseUrl }}`, on the `<script>` part, the line `this.baseUrl = this.ApiBaseUrl` triggers an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ApiBaseUrl' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mounted (Home.vue?76f2:207)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4219)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3139)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6346)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6565)
    at Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

--- Added code of main.js ---

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

fetch("config.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .catch((error) => {
    // ignore any errors
    console.warn(error);
    return {};
  })
  .then((config) => {
    Vue.prototype.ApiBaseUrl = config.ApiBaseUrl;
    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  });
```

Comment: where is `ApiBaseUrl` coming from? It isn't a prop, computed value, data or function.

Comment: I have updated the question, so I load the ApiBaseUrl from main.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mounted` hook could be a normal function to get access to `this`:

```
 mounted() {
    this.baseUrl = this.ApiBaseUrl;
  },
```

if you use an arrow function you should pass the component instance as parameter:

```
 mounted: (vm) => {//vm refers to this
    vm.baseUrl = vm.ApiBaseUrl;
  },
```